# Inspection error in scala method / play framework / rest

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm still learning scala so this might be a question with an easy answer, but I've been stuck on writing a single method over and over for almost a day, unable to get this code to compile.

I'm playing with the Play Framework and a reactive mongo template to learn how Scala and Play work.
I have a controller with a few methods, endpoints for a REST service.

The issue is about the following method, which accepts a list of json objects and updates those objects using the mongo reactive driver. The class has one member, `citiesFuture` which is of type `Future[JSONCollection]`.
The original class code which I'm adding this method to can be found here for context: [CityController on github](https://github.com/jonasanso/play-reactive-mongo-db/blob/master/app/controllers/CityController.scala)

```
def updateAll() = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  Json.fromJson[List[City]](request.body) match {
    case JsSuccess(givenCities, _) =>
      citiesFuture onComplete[Future[Result]] { cities =>
        val updateFutures: List[Future[UpdateWriteResult]] = for {
          city <- givenCities
        } yield cities.get.update(City.getUniqueQuery(city), Json.obj("$set" -> city))

        val promise: Promise[Result] = Promise[Result] {
          Future.sequence(updateFutures) onComplete[Result] {
            case s@Success(_) =>
              var count = 0
              for {
                updateWriteResult <- s.value
              } yield count += updateWriteResult.n
              promise success Ok(s"Updated $count cities")
            case Failure(_) =>
              promise success InternalServerError("Error updating cities")
          }
        }
        promise.future
      }
    case JsError(errors) =>
      Future.successful(BadRequest("Could not build a city from the json provided. " + Errors.show(errors)))
  }
}
```

I've managed to get this far with alot of trial and error, but I'm starting to understand how some of the mechanics of scala and Futures work, I think :) I think I'm close, but my IDE still gives me a single Inspection error just at the single closing curly brace above the line `promise.future`.

The error reads: **Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type Nothing**.
I've checked the expected return values for the Promise and onComplete code blocks, but I don't believe they expect **Nothing** as a return type.

Could somebody please explain to me what I'm missing, and also, I'm sure this can be done better, so let me know if you have any tips I can learn from!

Comment: Why using `Promise.future` where there is already `Future`? Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Because the Action needs a `Future[Result]` I thought this to be the only way, to construct a new Future which completes after all updates are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kinda on the right track but as @cchantep said, once you're operating in `Future`-land, it would be very unusual to need to create your own with `Promise.future`.

In addition, it's actually quite unusual to see `onComplete` being used - idiomatic Scala generally favors the "higher-level" abstraction of `map`ping over Futures. I'll attempt to demonstrate how I'd write your function in a Play controller:

**Firstly**, the "endpoint" just takes care of *one thing* - interfacing with the outside world - i.e. the JSON-parsing part. If everything converts OK, it calls a private method (`performUpdateAll`) that actually does the work:

```
def updateAll() = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  Json.fromJson[List[City]](request.body) match {
    case JsSuccess(givenCities, _) =>
      performUpdateAll(givenCities)
    case JsError(errors) =>
      Future.successful(BadRequest("Could not build a city from the json provided. "))
   }
}
```

**Next**, we have the private function that performs the update of multiple cities. Again, trying to abide by the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (in a functional sense - one function should do one thing), I've extracted out `updateCity` which knows how to update *exactly one city* and returns a `Future[UpdateWriteResult]`. A nice side-effect of this is code-reuse; you may find you'll be able to use such a function elsewhere.

```
private def performUpdateAll(givenCities:List[City]):Future[Result] = {

  val updateFutures = givenCities.map { city =>
    updateCity(city)
  }

  Future.sequence(updateFutures).map { listOfResults =>
    if (listOfResults.forall(_.ok)) {
      val count = listOfResults.map(_.n).sum
      Ok(s"Updated $count cities")          
    } else {
      InternalServerError("Error updating cities")
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this will work in exactly the same way as you intended yours to work. But by using `Future.map` instead of its lower-level counterpart `Future.onComplete` and matching on `Success` and `Failure` you get much more succinct code where (in my opinion) it's much easier to see the *intent* because there's less boilerplate around it.

We still check that every update worked, with this:

```
if (listOfResults.forall(_.ok))
```

which I would argue reads pretty well - all the results have to be OK!

The other little trick I did to tidy up was replace your "counting" logic which used a mutable variable, with a one-liner:

```
var count = 0
for {
  updateWriteResult <- s.value
} yield count += updateWriteResult.n
```

Becomes:

```
val count = listOfResults.map(_.n).sum
```

i.e. convert the list of results to a list of integers (the `n` in the `UpdateWriteResult`) and then use the built-in `sum` function available on lists to do the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! The way you explain it, the solution makes much more sense :)
I'm working to get it to work, I've added the updateCity function so it at least compiles, now I have an issue with the json being parsed, but I'm sure that once that's solved this will work, thanks again.
Edit: The json issue was me using the wrong location :), this works like a charm!